# After unlocking several feats on Humble version, how do I get the achievements on the Steam version?

Tags: achievements, shovel-knight

I've been playing the Humble version of Shovel Knight a number of times before switching to the Steam version. They both share the `%APPDATA%\Yacht Club Games\Shovel Knight` for storing settings and save games, so my progress and feats are still there. Which is good.

But I started playing the Steam version in hopes of getting the achievements tied to feats. Since I already got quite a number of the feats, what would I need to do to unlock their respective achievements?

Should I simply perform the same feat again, start a new game, or even wipe my progress and settings?

[image: Feats screenshot]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure how I missed it at first, but only after posting the screenshot that I took did I notice the "**<kbd>F4</kbd> Steam sync**" text in the top-right corner of the feats screen.

[image: F4 Steam sync]

After pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> on that screen, all my precious feats were immediately copied to my Steam achievements! Yay!

[image: Steam achievements]

I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume this should also work for the GoG version, since it uses the same directory for settings and save games.